# NodeJS Microservices by custom npm packages

Tags: node.js, express, npm, microservices, backend

I'm planning to develop a modular ERP that would run on each company server and have a custom set of modules. (here I mean by "module" as an ERP feature).

So I'd like to implement the microservice architecture without using containers or NestJS.
Since npm packages can be installed from a git repo, I'm thinking of make a npm module for each microservice and then install the microservices on a main project.
Each of those microservice modules would export an ExpressJS Router. And all the code needed by the microservices and also the main app, would be on a separated npm module.

The deployment or update of a microservice would be as simple as pushing the module changes to the git repo and run `npm install` on the main app project.

Does anyone knows about this or a similar implementation?
If never heard before (just like me) then what do you think?

I've researched about microservices and considered docker with kubernetes but I think it could be expensive and I'd must learn to control kubernetes with something like terraform.

I've also researched a little bit about nestJS but I don't like its design pattern is already fixed and I'd have to read lots of docs for a good implementation.